# Alternate of GroupBY clause in MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing, group-by, bigdata

I have one table having more than 100 Million records and 90 columns.
Search criteria can be on any column and also user can apply GroupBy on columns.

Also, I gave indexing on 10 fields which are frequently searched.

Actually, it is summary Report, so lots of arithmetic operations are performed on the query to generate the actual result.

I tried many ways to change query but did not get any success. Is there any alternate way to skip GroupBy or better way to write a query on Big Data?

Comment: Is it possible to share schema and query?

Comment: Is it really necessary to grant a user access to group by any column? In your case, you can pre-compute the arithmetic operations and store them in other table or a view. The solution really depends on the user API and also on the frequency of new writes to the database. Tell me if this helped you :)